# How to retrieve 0 as the first number in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

scenario:
I have a database having a record 001234 and I am calling it with `cmd.executescaler();` into a `int` variable. The problem is when I retrieve the saved data (`001234`) data from that variable it gives only `1234`. `00` in `001234` are important, this was the problem first coming in db where sql omits the first zero's then I changed the datatype to nvarchar which works, how I can retrieve the data on the form exactly `001234`.

Note: I cannot take the data into string as I have to also apply some calculations on them.

using Sql Server visual studio 2010 c#

Hope it is clear not vague. If you need more information tell me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you storing a numeric value as text in dbms? You should apply formatting in the final step.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. Either you get an integer (which has no leading zeros by definition) or a string.

Comment: Logically in integer zeros on left are of no use. Until & unless you convert it to string.

Comment: zeros on left are important my numeric numbers are 6 characters numbers only..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those leading zeros have some meaning and can't be left out, conversion can be done:

```
            int number = 0;
            string strNumber = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            if(int.TryParse(strNumber, out number))
            {
                // process number

                // if you want some output to be formatted with leading 
                // zeros you can use PadLeft method
                int totalNumberOfDigits = 6;
                string strResult = number.ToString().PadLeft(totalNumberOfDigits, '0');
            }
```

Comment: Perfect your method works, brilliant Thanks buddy,, And thanks all of you people, May God Bless us all.

Answer (score 4):

Numeric datatype don't have and can't have leading zeros. So the only way to have leading zeros is to store the value as a string.

However, this is just a matter of formatting the *output* that is shown to the user. You can read the database value into an `int` variable, do your calculations and when showing the value, you can do:

```
string displayValue = String.Format("{0:D6}", intValue);
```

and show the value of `displayValue`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **work on the Code side**:

```
string displayValue = String.Format("{0:D6}", intValue);
```

If you want to **work on the DB side** you need a **Pad function** that allows to write this kind of query:

```
SELECT dbo.PadString ('8', '0', 5)
->Result: 00008

SELECT dbo.PadString ('abc', '*', 12)
->Result: *********abc

SELECT dbo.PadString ('abc', '0', 7)
->Result: 0000abc
```

Create a function in T-SQL

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[PadString] 
  (@Seq varchar(16),
   @PadWith char(1),
   @PadLength int
  ) 
RETURNS varchar(16) AS

BEGIN 
  declare @curSeq varchar(16)

  SELECT @curSeq = ISNULL(REPLICATE(@PadWith, @PadLength - len(ISNULL(@Seq ,0))), '') + @Seq

  RETURN @curSeq
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason SQL does this is because 001234 = 1234 in any number format no matter what type it is. As a "Dirty" solution you could cast it as an int which will give you 1234, perform your calculations and then cast your answer back to string adding the leading zeros.

```
int myValue = Int32.Parse("001234");
int myAnswer = myValue * 2;

string myAnswerString = "00" + myAnswer.ToString();
```

The best way to go though would be to format your string as suggested by @Thorsten Dittmar. If possible, do not store numeric values in the database as varchar to begin with, however I know that this is sometimes a requirement, but the I cannot see the point on doing calculations on those values.

Comment: it is possible that the number only contains one zero on the left like 012345

Comment: Thanks @user1415295 Please share the solution then, we are all here to learn how, not only know what is possible and what not. Thanks J

Comment: no no actually i mean my numbers could contain more than one leading zero's

Answer (score 0):

you can use string.PadLeft() in c# after retrieving your number, as you have fixed length numbers

example from msdn,

```
string str = "forty-two";
char pad = '.';

Console.WriteLine(str.PadLeft(15, pad));    // Displays "......forty-two".
Console.WriteLine(str.PadLeft(2, pad));     // Displays "forty-two".
```